# What defines an "application" with regards to the Imgur API?

Tags: imgur

In the [Imgur API docs](https://apidocs.imgur.com/), it states that each client must register an application. I'm looking for clarification on what an application is because I'm working on a project for self-hosted software. Would each of my users need to register an application because they are interacting with the API from different domains or is it sufficient if I register an application for them and include the client ID in my distributed code?

Comment: I’m not entirely sure what it is that you’re creating? Are you creating an “app” that users will use? Or are you creating a framework that developers will bring into their own software? If the former then your app is the only app you would need to register. If the latter… don’t register an app at all. Each developer would do that themselves.

Comment: @Fogmeister It's user facing. The software is a module for [Foundry VTT](https://foundryvtt.com/) which will be available to install and use without looking at the code. Thanks for the advice!

Comment: Ah ok. In that case. Just register your app and users will just be users of your app.